# Determine if points lie on the graph of $f$ or$ f^{-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

I have $f(x) = \sqrt x$, which means $f^{-1}(x) = x^2$.

I need to determine if the points $(a, f(a))$ where $a \geq 0$ lies on the graph of $f$ or $f^{-1}$.  This was easier with points like $(2,4)$ or $(5, \sqrt 5)$ where I could easily plug in the numbers and solve the equation.  Does the same hold where I just use the terms $a$ and $f(a)$ to solve the problem?

Comment: A similar example would the point (f(a),a).

Comment: Hint: do you have a _definition_ of what "the graph of $f$" _means_, that you could compare to?

Comment: I would assume the graph f(x)= sqrt x

Comment: He is asking if you have the definition for "the graph of a function," in general.  If you do, the answer can be drawn from that.

Comment: Ah, it's symmetric about the line y = x.

Comment: Taken from Wikipedia: "In mathematics, the graph of a function $f$ is the collection of all ordered pairs $(x, f(x))$."  So clearly the general form is correct in your example.  If $a$ is in the domain then you can be sure the point is on the graph.

Comment: Which means f(a) = b and f^-1(b) = a.  Ok, I get it now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this comment evolved to the point of being an answer, so I will make it one:

Taken from Wikipedia: "In mathematics, the graph of a function $f$ is the collection of all ordered pairs $(x,f(x))$." So clearly the general form is correct in your example. If $a$ is in the domain then you can be sure the point is on the graph of $f$.

$(f(a),a)$ would not be on the graph of $f$ except for some specific $a$.